# laravel:8 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Tag' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to show and create tags but it showed an error "Error
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Tag' not found
[http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/create/"](http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/create/%22)

error line:

```
'tags' => Tag::all()
```

code:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('articles.create', [
        'tags' => Tag::all()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: A silly question, but - did you `use` the class?

Comment: @El_Vanja  paste.ofcode.org/F6pDNMhRid8fs2g8ntK8cY

Comment: So... no, you didn't. For future reference, please include additional information in the question itself by editing, as links can break in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use App\Models\Tag;
```

you are using model without using it in controller.